# Setting Spark Classpath on Amazon EMR

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-spark, emr

I am trying to run some simple jobs on EMR (AMI 3.6) with Hadoop 2.4 and Spark 1.3.1.  I have installed Spark manually without a bootstrap script.  Currently I am trying to read and process data from S3 but it seems like I am missing an endless number of jars on my classpath.

Running commands on spark-shell.  Starting shell using:

```
spark-shell --jars jar1.jar,jar2.jar...
```

Commands run on the shell:

```
val lines = sc.textFile("s3://folder/file.gz")
lines.collect()
```

The errors always look something like: "Class xyz not found".  After I find the needed jar and add it to the classpath, I will get this error again but with a different class name in the error message.

Is there a set of jars that are needed for working with (compressed and uncompressed) S3 files?

Comment: How did you build your application jar?

Comment: No application jar.  Running on the shell.

Comment: and did you add the libraries to your spark-shell? How do you lunch your spark-shell? Can you update with the command you are using?

Comment: updated to show command to start spark-shell

Comment: so do you have something like the following when you start you shell?  `SparkContext: Added JAR file:/path/to/jar/jar1.jar  at http://host:port/jars/jar1.jar with timestamp 1432826782616`

Comment: Yes I am seeing these.  One for each of the 20+ jars I am already adding to the classpath.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79033/discussion-between-eliasah-and-djelbow).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure out the jars needed for my classpath by following the logic in the AWS GitHub repo https://github.com/awslabs/emr-bootstrap-actions/tree/master/spark.

The install-spark and install-spark-script.py files contain logic for copying jars into a new 'classpath' directory used by the SPARK_CLASSPATH variable (spark-env.sh).

The jars I was personally missing were located in /usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/ and /usr/share/aws/emr/lib/

Comment: I see this is quite dated now, the config files invovled haven't moved past emr major version number 3, and we're in 5 now. 5.16.0 at current.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not imported the proper libraries from with-in the spark-shell.

To do so :

```
import path.to.Class
```

or more likely if you want to import the RDD class, per say:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
```

Comment: Turns out this is not an 'import' problem.  I am able to run this from a Cloudera VM no problem without it.